# WPF opening a new window from an event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

I'm trying to open a new window inside an event once it is triggered and im receiving: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invoke your code from the dispatcher:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate{

//your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

STA thread is the UI thread, so do not try to open a new window from another (worker?) thread.